# Codeigniter : Cannot Access Controller Subfolder in Shared Hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, shared-hosting

Hope you can help me with my problem. This is my first time deploying an Application into a shared hosting which is Hostgator Baby Plan. I used codeigniter framework to build the application. I created a subfolder under controller and it's working fine in my localhost but when I transfer it on the the web hosting all links that are in controller's sub folder is not accessible.
All I can access are those controllers that are not in sub folder. 
Do I need to configure something on shared host or in my application?
Please help.

```
application
-- controllers
---- api
------ users.php -> Not able to access but on my local its working
------ items.php -> Not able to access but on my local its working
---- welcome.php -> I can Access this
```

Comment: This should work.What do you mean by not working?Do you get any error?

Comment: I'm receiveing "404 Page Not FoundThe page you requested was not found." . In my local machine it's working. I can normally access it but when trasferred in the server, it didn't work

Comment: is it CI 404 error or your server sending 404 error.

Comment: it is CI 404 error. sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: That ,means its not your hosting problem.If your CI version is 3. Your files name should be 'Users.php' (uppercase). also provide the link for what you getting error.

Comment: Its now working! Thanks for your help. I'm using CI version 2 and the problem is that the filenames of the class controller in my subfolders started in capital letter but I'm accessing it in small letter. e.g. filename is controller/subfolder/Api.php but I'm accessing it in url as controller/subfolder/api instead of controller/subfolder/Api . Thank you for your help. it saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

May be you are developing your site with windows and you are hosting with linux.

Check your php version and select lastest php version, rename

> users.php -> Users.php

and rename your

> class users -> Users